# Best tool for digitally marking assignments?

Tags: software, grading, homework, assessment

I was wondering if anyone could recommend a good piece of software for marking digital (PDF) assignments. Specifically, I am marking a first-year mathematics course, and need to do the following for each assignment:

- Open student's PDF assignment
- Make annotations (really, the only two tools I use are **red pencil/pen** and **text comments**). I am using a Wacom pen tablet for this.
- Save a copy of the marked assignment in the original directory.
- Repeat x many.

I am currently using Foxit and was using Xodo previously, but neither tool feels quite right for the job. I would favour something that:

- Makes the above process quick and easy
- Interacts nicely with the Wacom tablet (Adobe Reader doesn't, for example)
- Is lightweight and easily usable (really only need pen and text tools, and possibly rotating pages every now and then. Everything else is clutter)
- Has a good workflow so I can mark as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What problems are they solving? Could you have a “quiz” with calculations and have interim answers so you trap the detail?

Comment: What platform (operating system) are you using? If you're on a Mac, you can annotate PDFs in the Preview application that comes with the OS.

Comment: @shoover: I'm using Windows.